# Strava-V3 & Javascript es6 generators = not compatible?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, ecmascript-6, generator

I'm using [node-strava-v3](https://github.com/UnbounDev/node-strava-v3) with Node 5.7 to retrieve JSON collections from Strava's API. Pretty simple actually, no problem actually. 
I just want to take the opportunity to try the ES6 Generators. So far so good I think I get the concept. But in the case of this Node-Strava-V3 API wrapper, the methods never return a value or a promise directly. Only Callbacks are allowed.
Which brings me to the question : how can I insert the ES6 Generators concept into play?

Take this : (this requires access_token you can request on the Strava portal)

```
var strava = require('strava-v3');
var mainActivity = {id: 504641206};
strava.activities.get(mainActivity, function (err, data){
  if(err){ console.log("Strava GET issue: ", err);
  /// consume the JSON data here...
};
//rest of the code
```

but can I use the generators to pause until this "strava.activities.get()" method ends?  this method does not return any, no value, no promise.

Thanks for all your suggestions

FJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this with generators and a library like [`co`](https://github.com/tj/co), but now we have [`async` functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) (ES2017, and can be transpiled for outdated environments).

Tangentially related: *Any* API that provides callbacks can be promise-ified:

```
const strava = require('strava-v3');
const mainActivity = {id: 504641206};
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    strava.activities.get(mainActivity, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve(data);
        }
    });
}).then(
    result => {
        //rest of the code
    },
    error => {
        // handle error
    }
);
```

In fact, that common pattern is codified in [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original):

```
const strava = require("strava-v3");
const promisify = require("util").promisify;
const stravaActivitiesGet = promisify(strava.activities.get);

const mainActivity = {id: 504641206};
stravaActivitiesGet(mainActivity).then(
    result => {
        //rest of the code
    },
    error => {
        // handle error
    }
);
```

There are multiple libraries that promise-ify a whole API at once (rather than per-function), such as [`node-promisify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promisify-node).

If we use `util.promisify` and an `async` function:

```
const strava = require("strava-v3");
const promisify = require("util").promisify;
const stravaActivitiesGet = promisify(strava.activities.get);

const mainActivity = {id: 504641206};
(async () => {
    try {
        const data = await stravaActivitiesGet(mainActivity);
        //rest of the code
    } catch (error) {
        // handle error
    }
})();
```

That mostly makes sense if you're doing other asynchronous things in the logic.

Comment: Thanks T.J., this makes things neat & clean. I'll check the libraries & the next ES versions as well. Looks promising :)